# Re-declare a global type inside a namespace in C++

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef

A type `Scalar` is declared out of any namespace in a file **type.h** :

```
typedef float Scalar;
```

I would like to re-declare this type inside a namespace `Hello` in a file **hello.h** :

```
namespace Hello 
{
     // definition of a type Hello::Scalar
     // that refers to the Scalar in type.h 
}
```

such that anywhere in the namespace `Hello`, the type `Hello::Scalar` refers to the one declared in **hello.h**, which refers to `Scalar` declared in **type.h** (which is `float`).

How to achieve is by ensuring that :

- the first `Scalar` is not in any namespace
- `Scalar` and `Hello::Scalar` have the same 'name' '*Scalar*'

I tried some *typedef* or *using* keywords without any results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace Hello {

    typedef ::Scalar Scalar;
}
```

should do the trick.